# 32 bit on 64 bit causing strange characters

Tags: server, 64-bit, 32-bit

I installed a 32 bit game server on 64 bit ubuntu server 14.04.2 LTS.  This required a few libraries, including lib32gcc.  Now, whenever I run apt-get, I get all kinds of strange characters.

The following is just an excerpt, you can see the entire output [here](http://pastebin.com/igcCmr4L):

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real:  is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: 8d°Ü8888888888888►!84►ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÁ▼|ðÁ87878787878787PuPuP∟Çq∟Çq∟ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: u8Q)+ is not a known library type
P)ÅqTÏ&)¾¹h@±ÉÖZc¾R↑§8482!Wµ5♥s83´ is not a known library type0wé9eBAÔضû
/sbin/ldconfig.real: úf☻of<♫µyOãv96K»☺>ÏH99$¡¾ ↕­¾86ÜNú¡∟90▲Ñù{¹Ã♥♫sq8e¥♀7§97±Hâgd8897t is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: 6Zn1íI`I²¼"♥}©¡ÞZªòÍS8dW91©→↔Ée♣♥í˘Ñ' is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real:  is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: J◄c↔§d©rGé98k_♂P↔6Ü ՅP▲¶u↕u874884瞀x"îR\±Òêz94☻{ÛþD·97Q¨9bàd¦ÐI8885ª¾ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ûåxvԉ[9482í83dN·ÙÄA)Ì~Ü↑\Våò       →=ÍL¿wé♦Ó↔c"¥8e7 is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ÿ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "fast" count="%zu" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "rest" count="%zu" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "current" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "max" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "mprotect" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "rest" count="%zu" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "current" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "max" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "total" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "mprotect" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: wÞûuu84m8797|95x9e|4O½Ì♦ÿuJQ82▼ŸD°Õá"ÔHE(4ضՋ97Þ↕,Å^u®80Ïw8b♠¡ÚjÌ:85‼→¾òUk82¯É9@▼8f¥­ó→é´Ú▲ñ9m7ø82⌂§½¥(9f²·ßa88¾¶%↨P³·Ö7ÌB^¤[Ñk~qö is not a known library type
87▼85üÐë㝀►ؽ{èV8eö§Û☺y8b87ÿö▬c»♀▲98]Å%º;oÞÜ\\Têèkב9b9eÛ♂¶$ZJZ²zDÜu°®↔ú▬c»­ëIսWG►í91|♫ͫbÍ÷♀a*ô=▬Ý)85 is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /9288ëê is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: 9d|Õ►ÜÄ is not a known library type
Ñ♠;Ì is not a known library typeT.ȏT.ð8d§þɏT.☻¦)8e{`^áۀA·7-ʚJ"}ÿyh87ÿìd9a¢~÷v►96↔â8aÁ§ψz®Nìö8d§þms85ÅêÌ
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ÿ¥9d<¥ö±-j&90)Öєtd☻>⌂[ÝKaÆø<81©♦-9b|↑å'?ó¾G>Áî¦→®»æäUønìrÓ+ª³¢÷↕R¥Ì↓opTԁÔ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: §ñ}♠@R¬b9f►9wë♠®b9f►8dÇà`¶Þb Ñ 91zÏ◄'¬~]Ù0Lë:}×]↓z,ÎÅ'òµEá is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: £÷9¾nÏ镶¸¥ïS808883?ùÿ¼7§§e²-.Ö)9c85►âY♦]82³« is not a known library type
♣L mjçVJ9f»?]g↓86ÕõãH[Ì>@iÖÚ♠¥Há2=97Ú§á♂¶►XÛøn1jfO÷86h↑Ǘ4ɤ9d►ÕðX91!1~¤♣ is not a known library type↨Ñ♥hÖÎ~▲]9aè¹/(91"ÞPÛÖÒÅ'♠"p.µéZñþÓçY91
fýÖ▲h9b½9c is not a known library typeêÙ-jÝù{9µï0↑∟sìX?97|T80Ìsقc☻;H85vàբ98Ëò¨§Ká6Y►ÜÏ쵶w↔
/sbin/ldconfig.real: c►lö"9f879e is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ®ä9 is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: {Ó§ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: 92â9 is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ÌÌÌ♀⌂▬kð is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: öu®♥ 85Ð is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: æÞ8 is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Þÿÿ8985Èúÿÿ 87¼ÿÿ81½ÈúÿÿÇ♥ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: üÿH8d:H81ì80 is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: 83ø♣t 83ø ▼D is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ∟ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ► is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: òº3 is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: öu®♥u.H8d=tÍ♀ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: öu®♥u.H8d=ÛÌ♀ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: 9d1 is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: 81Í0 is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: FýÿH8bt1ÒL896fE89n►83=0 is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real:  is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: þÿ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: 9e, is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: E85Àx♣E85Éy3D89ÀD)ÈÃf ▼D is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: øÿH85ÀI89Å 84)◄ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ¨»+ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ÿ9e+ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: r90♠ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ç98) is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: -98) is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ÿ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ÿ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ↕ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ‼ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real:  is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real:  is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: 8d°Ü8888888888888►!84►ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÁ▼|ðÁ87878787878787PuPuP∟Çq∟Çq∟ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: u8Q)+ is not a known library type
P)ÅqTÏ&)¾¹h@±ÉÖZc¾R↑§8482!Wµ5♥s83´ is not a known library type0wé9eBAÔضû
/sbin/ldconfig.real: úf☻of<♫µyOãv96K»☺>ÏH99$¡¾ ↕­¾86ÜNú¡∟90▲Ñù{¹Ã♥♫sq8e¥♀7§97±Hâgd8897t is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: 6Zn1íI`I²¼"♥}©¡ÞZªòÍS8dW91©→↔Ée♣♥í˘Ñ' is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real:  is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: J◄c↔§d©rGé98k_♂P↔6Ü ՅP▲¶u↕u874884瞀x"îR\±Òêz94☻{ÛþD·97Q¨9bàd¦ÐI8885ª¾ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ûåxvԉ[9482í83dN·ÙÄA)Ì~Ü↑\Våò       →=ÍL¿wé♦Ó↔c"¥8e7 is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ÿ is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "fast" count="%zu" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "rest" count="%zu" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "current" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "max" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "mprotect" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "rest" count="%zu" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "current" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "max" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "total" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: "mprotect" size="%zu"/> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: \BEÕìtãԕ{a,►Ü稙ðâkP96t87c§♠õ²` is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: \BEÕìtãԕ{a,►Ü稙ðâkP96t87c§♠õ²` is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: )ËóA▬ô8cý[Óùñå> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: )ËóA▬ô8cý[Óùñå> is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ♠Ëî¼2þKþ9´=_zÛ͆Íæ½↕´8♀190,↓ÝÝðØ↔‼w2z♫¢86­I}_Û      Z뇛↑ã_↨;Ï §ÏZ↕Ý¶Zº▼↓êt9d9e96§֌¹ Á↨õ849896Ԥ¿þWM↕NBL99p‼BC§NV@→Rzݹûqö is not a known library type
ç▬rͣ¨T8címG♣89☻漓íNÊT81å▼¤ is not a known library type7¶96g9a↨lÎ݌§IÍS³82áåw
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ø;:8a£²ÆrȅE is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: §3áñzBQx▲Y¾)L"♠ü@MÊQ«Jj♦èkcS♠9d8a♦ü85¨ã92íêڻë§ë>99ý²̽¦→>$" is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: sP9ciÌ8Øæ94Laè(♥¬Ór[>ÎØ◄♂¾¸87 Iұ8c¡ûa84ºwŲ§        2¹±Q99Í[º)½&ïbhYÕNa ÉK«29aõ88"×GxÆlA↨ôS9â܏¥`}Å 8eÀ~§↓\rK▬?Ge抬0ù¢O}¬♥7ÏVÍjà◄q!8∟U88.☺ is not a known library type
1û8b9aÊ↓KôQÍIUÜþ¿53~¼C¹à®♥8aݛ9d+â⌂»<☺û3=95Û/^♀& is not a known library type
~LTôG84j♥88♂£828a is not a known library typeK9c93ýE®ù÷81↓Ôu¸mZðÞB☺☻>8^²õ чY,82áHoы812{9d9c86׫u879ëEovÎt"µµ6àÃu95/¦\ªãl>a~zEbY±\
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Ô2m8dc▬.þÃ2Øå0©F95çÏȟ%@mö is not a known library type
§Þ¶9a♂lû9eTO»Ýköû9a9790c‼¸Æöì9ed\93Ëy9bÁ Èâæ>n8088¨rÕÎ^ÙÅõâM½∟ÍÛ)»}ö is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: ^ÑyÓegu°p.Ê↨9{+o   97²♥↕G˱‼◄aJ92±-6/­▲îa198Q5®ï83§ is not a known library type
```

Don't misinterpret, it certainly seems to work fine, but I'm sure that sort of output can't be good.  How do I fix it?

**For clarification:**
The game server is [Neverwinter Nights](http://www.neverwinternights.info/dedicatedserver.htm) (the original).  I only mention it as it may help diagnose the library at fault.

I checked my `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory, There don't appear to be any files with strange characters.  You can find the output [here](http://pastebin.com/kHfNft6s).

Comment: to find files containing a string you may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some garbage file names in your library path somewhere, made up of these strings. You will need to find them on your disk and remove them, to get rid of this problem. You should look in the paths listed within the files in the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory.

Comment: added ls -a results to my question

Comment: I wasn't asking for a list of files. I was stating that ldconfig is finding these files somewhere on your file system, and complaining that they are not known library types. These files most likely exist somewhere within the directories which are listed within those configuration files.

Comment: I don't understand, what are you asking me to do, search my entire system for files with these special characters and whitespace characters as file names?

Comment: Well, no, not your _entire_ file system. Only the directories which are listed in those conf files. As I said it appears that ldconfig is trying to identify files with those names as libraries, and is not able to do so, and it prints the errors.

Comment: edited with the info you requested.  No strange character filenames in the directories listed in those files.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue for a long time. For me, it was finally the /etc/ld.so.conf file with the /usr/local/lib/libopencv_* path. I commented out the path and I no longer see the garbage printing it out.